# Обработка нескольких IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, xamarin, anglesharp

Ситуация: В методе происходит парсинг данных:

```
var CompareStatLeftLevel_ = documentleft.All.Where(m =>
m.LocalName == "li" &&
m.HasAttribute("class") &&
m.GetAttribute("class").Contains("user-profile__data-item")
).ElementAt(2).TextContent.ToString();
```

Нужный элемент с индексом [2] всегда последний в списке "user-profile__data-item". Но иногда он может быть с индексом [1]. Тогда логично было бы написать

```
try{...ElementAt(2)...}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
{...ElementAt(1)...}
```

Но что делать если индекс будет [0]?

Нашел информацию про использование "when" в блоке "catch", но что туда передавать?

Comment: `m.GetAttribute("class").Contains("user-profile__data-item").Last()` ?

Comment: @tym32167 в ответы. Топикстартеру: а почему не `document.QuerySelector("li.user-profile__data-item").LastOrDefault()?.TextContent` ?

Comment: @AK я наобум написал, не уверен, что это вообще скомпилится :)

Comment: Exception-Driven Development не есть хорошо. Вернее, совсем плохо. Почему бы сперва не определять количество элементов в отфильтрованной коллекции, а потом обращаться к нужному. Хотя это уже реализовано в `Last`/`LastOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваш элемент последний - то можете использовать `.Last()` или `.LastOrDefault()` из арсенала Linq (это же IEnumerable)

При этом вместе с `.LastOrDefault()` можете использовать Null-условный оператор `?.` если у вас версия C# 6 и выше - будет удобнее обращаться к полям.

```
.Contains("user-profile__data-item").LastOrDefault()?.TextContent
```

И ещё хочу заметить - не совсем относящееся к вопросу. Я бы записал ваш пример не как

```
documentleft.All.Where(m =>
m.LocalName == "li" &&
m.HasAttribute("class") &&
m.GetAttribute("class").Contains("user-profile__data-item")
```

А более кратко:

```
document.QuerySelectorAll("li.user-profile__data-item")
```